# Problema na criação de chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql

Estou com problemas para criar uma chave estrangeira dessas tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
ALTER TABLE `tb_permissao_view` ADD  CONSTRAINT
`fk_tb_permissao_view_tb_sistema_pagina`
FOREIGN KEY (`cd_pagina`)
REFERENCES `tb_sistema_pagina` (`cd_pagina`);
```

Erro:

```
ALTER TABLE `tb_permissao_view` ADD CONSTRAINT
`fk_tb_permissao_view_tb_sistema_pagina` FOREIGN KEY (`cd_pagina`)     
REFERENCES `tb_sistema_pagina` (`cd_pagina`)
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: 
a foreign key constraint fails (`portal`.`#sql-4ee_f`, CONSTRAINT 
`fk_tb_permissao_view_tb_sistema_pagina` FOREIGN KEY (`cd_pagina`) REFERENCES 
`tb_sistema_pagina` (`cd_pagina`))
```

Comment: `tb_permissao_view` tem dados gravados já ou ambas estão vazias?

Comment: Sim,as duas tabelas possuem registros.

Comment: Provavelmente há valores em `tb_permissao_view` na coluna `cd_pagina` que não existem em `cd_pagina` da tabela de referencia `tb_sistema_pagina`. Cheque se realmente há valores divergentes nessas duas colunas.

Comment: Muito obrigado brother!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme dito nos comentários, o erro é disparado porque há valores na coluna `cd_pagina` da tabela  `tb_permissao_view` que não existem na coluna `cd_pagina` da tabela de referencia para chave estrangeira `tb_sistema_pagina`.

Todos os valores da coluna `foreign key` devem existir na coluna a qual ela está sendo referenciada, e como você disse que já há dados em ambas as tabelas, cheque se na coluna `cd_pagina` da tabela `tb_permissao_view` não há dados divergentes da tabela a qual ela possui uma relação de chave estrangeira(no caso a tabela `tb_sistema_pagina`).

**Referências:**

[ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21660862/5524514)